# Jupyter notebook - "No module named keras", but it was imported

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook

I'm running Jupyter notebook in a conda virtual environment (Ubuntu), and first entered:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
```

As you can see in the image below, it appears that keras has been imported.  However, when I try to import a function from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn I get an error message suggesting that keras hasn't been imported.  What am I missing here??

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why (and am open to answers!), but the following syntax results in no errors:

```
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
```

Comment: Tensorflow comes with its own keras. You installed `tensorflow` but not `keras`.

Comment: this works on tensorflow 2.0.0 ! thank you! (Keras was included in TensorFlow 2.0.0)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `keras` installed as separate package as well.

`pip install keras`